# Jest Equality test fails

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

```
 await expect(process(event)).rejects.toThrow(
      new BadRequestError("{ message: request parsing failed, cause: { message: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 1 }}")
    );
```

Fails with error "Received message and cause: serializes to the same string". How can I fix this?